# Get only change node value in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the `ref.on()` function to monitor the change in firebase nodes, 
but there is a problem, `ref.on()` gives whole database record.
How can I get only those rows/nodes whose state is changed

```
function watch()
{
    riderequests.once('value', function(snapshot)
       {
        alert("change");
        var newrequest = snapshot.val();
      }
  }
```

Comment: did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase provide events `child_added`, `child_changed`, `child_removed` for handling different events of adding, modifying and removing a child node from firebase. Read this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-changed).

According to Firebase docs:-

> The child_changed event is triggered any time a child node is
>   modified. This includes any modifications to descendants of the child
>   node. It is typically used in conjunction with child_added and
>   child_removed to respond to changes to a list of items. The snapshot
>   passed to the event callback contains the updated data for the child.

For getting the details of changed nodes use `child_changed` event. Basically this events fires whenever a child node is changed. It will result the snapshot of changed node.

```
riderequests.on('child_changed', function(snapshot){
    var newrequest = snapshot.val();
    console.log(newrequest);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To only get the specific row/node that changed, then inside your `ref()` you need to reference those nodes, example if you have this:

```
users
  userid
      name:peter
  userid
      name: john
```

then to only get the changed node, you can do this:

```
 ref().child("user").child(userid); //this will only give you the change in the logged in userid node
```

Also, you can just use a query like:

```
orderByChild("userid").equalTo(username);
```

which will give you only that specific node.

`on`

> Listens for data changes at a particular location.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on

You can also access a specific node change by doing this when retrieving:

```
 var newrequest = snapshot.val().name;
```

assuming `name` is a node in your firebase database.